# Make variable hold value after file is closed

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Just like the title suggests, I am looking for a way to make a variable hold its value even after the Excel 2010 file containing the VBA code is closed, and retrieve it with its last value, the next time I open the file.

Edit: I am aware of the fact that I can store the data "externally" outside of the VBA code, either in a cell or in an external file or in another way. I am looking for a way involving ONLY the VBA code of the said Excel file. An answer indicating that this is impossible, is an acceptable answer too, of course.

Comment: Can't you just save it to a worksheet cell and retrieve it later?

Comment: @douglaslps I thought this would be implied by the question, but as I see it is probably not. I am looking for  way, NOT involving storing the data I need in a cell. It's just a specific chucnk of data I do not want to be exposed on a cell in the open worksheet.

Comment: What about saving the data to a file and retrieving it later? Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085615/how-can-i-write-to-a-text-file-reliably-from-excel-vba

Comment: @douglaslps see edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something similar to:

```
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add _
Name:="Version Number", _
LinkToContent:=False, _
Type:=msoPropertyTypeNumber, _
Value:=7
```

As already discussed in [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/8711-there-way-store-value-visual-basic-applications-permanently.html).

Comment: I will test it soon.